# Different excel CLSID's for Excel cause issues with Interop in C# program

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, dcom

Basically I just need to know the difference between these 2 CLSID's.  I have server, clean install, newly imaged with office.  In DCOM under Excel Application I have an APPID of {00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.  I've set specific Identity and launch permissions for this AppID.

When I run my app which is converting a Excel file, I get:

> Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.

I looked up that CLSID ID, it is also an Excel Application GUID.  This is not what is listed in DCOM though.  So I think I have a conflict here?  Possibly different versions of office or x86 vs x64 archs competiting with each other on the same box perhaps??  Im not sure how Im supposed to set an Identity User on {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} since it is not the one listed in DCOM.  I have looked around but haven't found much on this subject.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Small update regarding this issue with fix!!!!!

While I was willing to accept the answer below as interop is bad automation for server based applications/services.  I know this is true.  It turns out in my case I had a bad dcomperm.exe  utility I had gotten from somewhere.  I was having issues getting the Windows 7 .NET 4.0 SDK to install so instead of fighting that issue, I grabbed a compiled DcomPerm from the web somewhere.  Bad idea.  This morning I found a way around the SDK install issue.  I was then able to compile my own DcomPerm.exe tool from the SDK reference (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\com\fundamentals\dcom\dcomperm).  This tool worked.  No more identity error.

I wasn't getting an error with the old DcomPerm tool either, but somehow it was not wiring everything up correctly.  Obviously with Interop being kind of a touchy, non enterprise solution, this all makes sense.

Comment: Are you running this program inside a service or inside IIS? If so, you may want to read the KB article "[Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757)", there are many issues you can run in to and it looks like you are running in to one of them. The short version is switch to the Open XML SDK if possible, it can read xlsx files and does not have the problems the COM interop stuff does.

Comment: This is a Service application.  And I agree, Interop sucks.  But for now, it has to stay.  Here is the main issue, if I go into DCOM, change the user to interactive and then change the user back to specific user I initially setup the server with, I don't get the error anymore.  I should mention, I'm initially using DcomPerm.exe to setup the Identity User.    It seems to work fine.   So Im just not sure what is happening when I set the user in the GUI vs when I set the user programmatically using he commanline tool.

Comment: The interop tool requires a user profile to be loaded to function, changing the user and changing it back keeps the profile loaded after you change it back. See the "User Identity" bullet in the KB article i linked to. And just to remind you, also from that page "*Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.*"

Comment: You said interop has to stay, but why does it have to stay? what feature of interop are you using that is not available to you in the [Office Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) (for example do you need to support .xls files)? If you could include the why we may be able to help you find a work around that makes that specific feature work without getting the enitre interop to work.

Comment: This is a conversion tool.  OpenXML works much better for the xlsx and docx office stuff.  But we get really old stuff coming through this conversion engine.  Word 6.0, Excel 5.0, etc.   The new interop libraries can read these old versions of Office.  Im really not trying to defend Interop here, I hate it.  I just don't have another solution at this time.  And even if I did, it would  take a lot of time to implement the change and release it to production in my environment.  But I'm all ears.  Thanks for the input Scott!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use components designed for the server-side execution (for example, such as Aspose provides) or just use the Open XML SDK in case of open XML files (.xslx and etc.), see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

As was mentioned in comments earlier, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.